# Как сделать перенос в ячейке при работе с phpexcel

Tags: phpexcel, php

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Пользуюсь phpexcel'ем, причем не первый день. Одну штуковину упорно не могу найти в мануале (или нет ее там). Ищу перенос внутри ячейки. Вот допустим вам нужно вставить 200 знаков в ячейку, и они не влезают. В экселе есть кнопка - перенос текста. Вот интересует как нужную ячейку отформатировать, что бы этот перенос был. Можно ли так вообще?

Смысл в том, что текст помещается в ячейке, путем автоматического переноса по строкам. Вот собственно и все, только команды не знаю, ее и спрашиваю.

p.s.

```
// выдернул из кода

// выравниваю как надо
$page->getStyle("".$jax."".$stroka."")->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);
$page->getStyle("".$jax."".$stroka."")->applyFromArray(array("font" => array( "bold" => true)));

// вставляю данные, и проклятая переменная $for, неприлично длинная
$page->setCellValue("".$jax."".$stroka."", "".$for."");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Насколько мне не изменяет память, то так:

```
$page->getStyle("".$jax."".$stroka."")->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

Comment: спасибо. функция все же есть.

Comment: Небольшое уточнение. Эта функция работает только с обычными ячейками. Вариант с переносом в объединенных ячейках такой: делаем ширину какой-либо неиспользуемой колонки идентичной ширине нашей объединенной колонки, пишем туда данные, применяем *setWrapText(true)*, а потом скрываем колонку при помощи *setVisible(false)*.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо \n ввести chr(10) - перевод каретки

Comment: Не пишите коментарий как ответ

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Если нам известно количество объединенных ячеек, то вот такой вариант работает и для объединенной ячейки:

$file->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('D1:E1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);

Похоже, что любой стиль будет работать таким образом для объединенных ячеек.

Answer (score 0):

Применить стили из массива

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2')->getAlignment()->applyFromArray(
         array(
             'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
             'vertical'   => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
             'rotation'   => 0,
             'wrap'       => TRUE
         )
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Как замена ALT+ENTER в Excel:

```
"string 1" .chr( 13 ) .chr( 10 ) ."string 2"
```

или так:

```
"string 1" .PHP_EOL ."string 2"
```

Comment: добавьте больше деталей в ваш ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer